# sidebar navigation elements not changing color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, I have the following HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" data-ng-controller="NavbarController">
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/a')}" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/a">a</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/b')}" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/b" >b</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/c')}" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/c" >c</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/d')}" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/d" >d</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/e')}" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/e" >e</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/f')}" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/f">f</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/g')}" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/g">g</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-ng-click="action()" data-ng-show="user.admin"><a href="#/h">h</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
....
```

I am trying to control the color of the individual navbar elements when they are hovered over or clicked on, however I don't seem to be having much luck.

From what I can gather from reading I need to focus on `:hover` and `:active` but no matter which way I try the CSS selectors I can't get it to change color.

How can I get the individual elements of the navbar to have a custom hover and active color?

Comment: I arranged your codes: http://jsfiddle.net/cocLx2u9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this...

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a50mhcve/)

Here I use **nth-child** in `css`

```
li:nth-child(1):hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can t able to comment due to my reputation. So giving it in answer.You can get this done by iterating over the `nav-item` class using .each and get `data-ng-class` attribute using that you can define your own css properties for each element.